# Can const functions call non-const functions on local objects?

Tags: c++, memory, constants

I have a question regarding const functions: can a const function call non-const functions on local objects in the function? Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
template <class T>
Set<T> Set<T>::setUnion (const Set<T> & other) const
{
    Set<T> unionSet; //create union set
    unionSet.merge(internalStorage); //merge it with our current set
    unionSet.merge(other.internalStorage); //merge it with other set, duplicates will not be added

    return unionSet;
}
```

This function takes two sets and returns the union of the sets. The problem though is that the merge function is not const and the merge function also calls the add function which is also not const, so I cannot see any other way to create a union set with solely these two functions given that the setUnion function has to be const.

**PS:** I know the solution without doing a const function, the reason I'm doing it this way is because my professor defined it as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The only restriction on a `const` member function is that it can't modify the object its called on; it can modify any other (non-const) object.

Comment: Exception: `mutable` members.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Indeed, there are various nuances to the meaning of `const` which aren't relevant to this question. The relevant point is that it doesn't prevent modification of anything other than `*this`.

Answer (score 1):

A `const` member function means that the `this` it receives has type roughly equivalent to `T const *const this`<sup>1</sup>.

That means you can't invoke any non-const functions *via `this`*, but it does *not* affect anything you do that *doesn't* go through `this` (explicitly or implicitly).

---

<sup>1. Technically, you can't really write out the type of `this` truly correctly, but the type I've given here is close enough for the current discussion.</sup>